# checking out the code from SVN which was modified on the current date

Tags: svn

I need to checkout the code from the SVN which was modified and checked in on the current date.This has to be done using ANT, I have the script which checks out the entire code but that is too time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you need the files which are modified on a particular date? You can use [revision ranges](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn-book.html#svn.tour.revs.dates) to get the revisions which contain the changesets. But you can't checkout only those files, cause in SVN you can checkout only a single directory as a smallest entity. Based on what you wrote you can think about using simply an svn update instead of a full checkout, but i'm not sure what you like to achieve.

Comment: what i need to acheieve is i want a list of files and those files which have been checked in on the current date using ant script....

Comment: i tried using revision for date but it give me error saying a date in the format as specified in dateFormatter attribute....

Comment: Via the date ranges in the link i gave you could get a list of revisions you need to take a look at ...